# Is it possible to lock one UV island and scale other (same) to be the same size as the locked one?

Tags: uv

[image]I have tried pinning the big island and Ctrl + A (averaging both of the islands), but that scales both of them down (making them the same size). I want the big one to not change its size and only the small one to scale up to match the big one. I hope it makes sense.

Thanks,

Comment: Hello :). There's a *Texel density* addon, that could work very well for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snapping

[image]

Or if they are the same size - by using the Texel Density Checker Addon https://gumroad.com/l/CEIOR

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, you saved me a lot of time!